# NSStream vs. NSURLConnection simultaneous open TCP

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp, nsurlconnection, nsstream

I still need an understanding of these things, anyway, does NSStream or NSURLConnection support multiple open TCP, say for example,

```
www.xyz.com port:4040
www.xyz.com port:5050
www.xyz.com port:5150
```

This is a only one host.

Which of the two can support the task of simultaneously opening a TCP port and keeping it open for a stated period of time, on the event none does, is there any existing iOS class/method that I can use to achieve this behavior.

My end goal is to create multiple TCP connections at a given time.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. you can create multiple TCP connections to same host but different ports using NSStream and CFSocket...

Comment: Have you tried it, Do you have any samples?, Also does this evidently states that NSURLConnection is too abstracted that we can't add customizations to it?

Comment: I cannot comment on NSURLConnection abstraction, but yes, I have created multiple connections to same IP address twice using AsyncSocket (http://cocoadev.com/wiki/AsyncSocket)